# Rails 3 Rounting changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am converting Rails 2.3.10 application to Rails 3.0.3. In Routes.rb i made changes for legacy rounting like the below :

**Rails 2 :**

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

**Equivalent Rails 3 is :**

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(/:format)))'
```

**The problem is  i have the two more legacy routes format**

```
map.connect ':controller.:format'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id/:section'
```

I don't know, how can i covert the above rails 2 routes to equivalent Rails 3. Can any one help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
match ':controller(.:format)'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(/:section)))'
```

Comment: c:/jruby-1.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routi
ng/mapper.rb:164:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentEr
ror)

Comment: When i try with match ':controller(.:format)', i get the above error.